# How to ensure that a method exists in the real object when mocked?

Tags: phpunit, mockery

I would like my test to fail if I mock an interface using Mockery and use a shouldReceive with a non-existing method. Looking around didn't help.

For instance :

With an interface :

```
interface AInterface {
    public function foo();
    public function bar();
}
```

And a test case :

```
function testWhatever{
    Mockery::mock('AInterface')->shouldReceive('bar');
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

The test will pass.

Now, refactoring time, bar method is not needed in one place (let's say it's needed on several places) and is suppressed from the interface definition but the test will still pass. I would like it to fail.

Is it possible to do such a thing using mockery (and to be able to do the same thing with a class instead of an interface) ?
Or does a workaround exist with some other tool or a testing methodology ?

Not sur if this can be understood as is,  will try to make a clearer description of the issue if needed.

Answer (score 4):

To ensure that Mockery doesn't allow you to mock methods that don't exist, put the following code in your PHPUnit bootstrap file (if you want this behavior for **all** tests):

```php
\Mockery::getConfiguration()->allowMockingNonExistentMethods(false);
```

If you just want this behavior for a specific test case, put the code in the `setUp()` method for that test case.

Check [this section of the Mockery manual on Github](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/mockery/configuration.html) for more information.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. Will try it later and mark it as valid if so :)

Comment: Hi @Eugene M. Totally forgot about this question. Made some tests today and your solution appears to work for class mocks but not for interface mocks. Did I miss something or is the thing impossible after all ? (I can share my test code with you if needed ;) )

Comment: @SelrahcD Honestly I'm not sure ... I saw that the Mockery documentation had moved, so I updated the link in the answer to the relevant page ... it doesn't seem to speak specifically to classes vs. interfaces though.

Comment: Made some more tests with a coworker and we concluded that this works only for classes. I don't know if I have to mark your answer as the correct one because I was speaking of interfaces and not classes but this helped me a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make sure that the method is called only one time, you can use **once()**.

Suppose that the **class AImplementation**, implements the interface **AInterface**, and you wanna tested that the method is called, an example could be:

> Mockery::mock('AImplementation')->shouldReceive('bar')->once();

You can also use: **zeroOrMoreTimes()**, **twice()** or **times(n)**, checkout the [repo at github](https://github.com/padraic/mockery). Also, I recommend you [this tutorial](https://tutsplus.com/tutorial/easier-testing-with-mockery/) by Jeffrey W

Comment: I'm aware of the counting method in mockery but this doesn't ensure that the bar method exists in AImplementation. Like I said in the question I'm not sur that it was clearly expressed, maybe I should do a question refactoring :) Thanks anyway and que tenga un buen día !

Comment: once() make sure that the method is called, so the bar method exist in your production code

Comment: In my production code yes, but not in the AImplementation, only in the mocked object.